# Ansible. Updating the hostvars variable

Tags: ansible

If, during the execution of the playbook, we change the host file in **host_vars** (i.e. add a new variable), how then can we get this variable in **hostvars** in the current execution of the playbook? When you run it again, it appears in **hostvars**.

**UPDATE** 01:

Here's an example, it doesn't work (

The task **Debug 3** should display **test_1** instead of **VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!**

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: mon

  tasks:
  - name: Debug 1
    debug:
      var: hostvars.mon.test_1

  - name: Add vars for host_vars
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    blockinfile:
      path: "{{ inventory_dir }}/host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname }}.yml"
      marker: "# {mark}: {{ item.key }}"
      block: |
        {{ item.key }}: {{ item.value }}
    with_dict:
    - {test_1: "test_1"}

  - name: Debug 2
    debug:
      var: hostvars.mon.test_1

  - name: Clear facts
    meta: clear_facts

  - name: Refresh inventory
    meta: refresh_inventory

  - name: Setup
    setup:

  - name: Debug 3
    debug:
      var: hostvars.mon.test_1
```

Result:

```
PLAY [Test] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [mon]

TASK [Debug 1] *****************************************************************
ok: [mon] => {
    "hostvars.mon.test_1": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [Add vars for host_vars] **************************************************
changed: [mon -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': 'test_1', 'value': 'test_1'})

TASK [Debug 2] *****************************************************************
ok: [mon] => {
    "hostvars.mon.test_1": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [Setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [mon]

TASK [Debug 3] *****************************************************************
ok: [mon] => {
    "hostvars.mon.test_1": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
mon                        : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

On restart:

```
PLAY [Test] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [mon]

TASK [Debug 1] *****************************************************************
ok: [mon] => {
    "hostvars.mon.test_1": "test_1"
}

TASK [Add vars for host_vars] **************************************************
ok: [mon -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': 'test_1', 'value': 'test_1'})

TASK [Debug 2] *****************************************************************
ok: [mon] => {
    "hostvars.mon.test_1": "test_1"
}

TASK [Setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [mon]

TASK [Debug 3] *****************************************************************
ok: [mon] => {
    "hostvars.mon.test_1": "test_1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
mon                        : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Maybe there is a way to change **hostvars** manually in the process?

Comment: Frankly, that sounds like a Bad Idea.  Why would you do that?

Comment: @Jack, Well, for example, grafana-loki is installed and writes its port (3100) to host_vars/host.yml, which can then be read by another playbook or role to know this port of grafana-loki.

Comment: That port is chosen randomly by the grafana-loki installation?

Comment: @Jack, loki just for an example, please take a look **UPDATE 01**

Comment: The `meta: refresh_inventory` re-executes dynamic inventory scripts.  There is no reason to reload static inventory, because changing those files during execution is a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Ansible to reread inventory (including host_vars). Generally I'd say that changing inventory on-fly is a code smell, but there are few valid cases.

```
- name: Refreshing inventory, SO copypaste
  meta: refresh_inventory
```

Comment: Please, see the **UPDATE 01**

Comment: I cannot think of a valid case.  Static inventory files should be in version control.

Comment: We have a valid case when molecule scenario tests 'app and workers'. We need to install app to be able to generate temporary worker inventory. This done via 'refresh' after app installation. It's rare edge cases. Generally, I would say, any 'refresh inventory' is like 'unsafe' in Rust. Pay attention to those places.